# How to limit tab label size?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have these tabs which I have to insert into very small space.

[image]

I want to display only the first six letters of the tab labels if the tab is not selected. Is this possible in JavaFX?

Answer (score 1):

From the api doc:

**The tabs width and height can be set to a specific size by setting the min and max for height and width**. TabPane default width will be determined by the largest content width in the TabPane. This is the same for the height. If a different size is desired the width and height of the TabPane can be overridden by setting the min, pref and max size.

Check API doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html

Answer (score 0):

To be perfect in what amount of letters is shown, you can add listener on selected property of the tab, and when tab becomes selected - setText to be the whole text, when become unselected, make it to be only 6 letters. You can store the whole title in the userData property.